# Generate a View/Page from a model in Blazor with Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, blazor

I am very new to Blazor and i am wondering if there is a  way to generate a View from a Model and his Controller like with Razor to develop faster. In Visual Studio it is possible by right clicking on View Folder and choosing the Controller that we want.

Imagine having a User Model with data like Name, Adress etc. In Razor it is possible to generate a View (HTML, JS) containing those attributes related to User by choosing the model that we want (Edit, Create, Delete, etc).Then a complete form will show up with a generated HTML and JS in Pages Folder.

Comment: I am not aware of any such wizards at this time in Visual Studio for Blazor.  But it's not too hard to write a form for data input.  There is a good sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a whole night of searching I found that this option given by Visual Studio is related with Scafolding and it is only avalaible for Blazor Server Side and Blazor Hosted applications. [More information in the Syncfusion documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/extension/blazor-extension/visual-studio/scaffolding)